# Something wrong with predicate in prolog-same results for every date

Tags: prolog, program-slicing

I have the below code in Prolog and the problem is that when i run the code it returns for every data the same result.

```
?- run(Diagnosis).
Diagnosis='There is no problem with anemia'.
```

The KB is in another file and load it and in start predicate i load patient3 for example and it should return

```
Diagnosis ='Iron deficiency'
```

Note that the start predicate is only for check if the code works right for now!
When i run this file with trace it shows that first tries the first rules.. It fails in **check_RTC** when it tries to go to the other rule the predicate **symptoms** returns **symptomNeg**..but why?
It should take from the beginning all the data and make the checks for the every next rule, until to find the rules that doesn't fail.

```
:- ['kb_anemia_V4.pl'].

run(Diagnosis) :-
  clause(kb_da(patient3,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]),Body),
  rule(kb_da(patient3,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]),Diagnosis). 

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  %OK 
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia),
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcUp2),
        check_HBS(ElectricalHb,hbSZero), 
        Diagnosis  = 'Spherocytcocis.'.

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcUp2),
        check_HBS(ElectricalHb,hbsUpZero), 
        Diagnosis  = 'Drepanocytocis.'.     

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcUp2),
        check_HBS(ElectricalHb,hbSZero) ; 
        check_HBS(ElectricalHb,hbsUpZero), 
        Diagnosis  = 'No problem with Spherocytocis or Drepanocytocis.'.    

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvLow),
        checkFerritin(FullBloodTest,ferHigh),
        checkElectrofHb([Symptoms,ElectricalHb],yesElectr),
        Diagnosis='Thalassemia'.

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvLow),
        checkFerritin(FullBloodTest,ferHigh),
        checkElectrofHb([Symptoms,ElectricalHb],noElectr),
        Diagnosis  = 'There is not problem with anemia,probably hemochromatosis,because of High feritin.'.  

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvLow),
        checkFerritin(FullBloodTest,ferLow),
        check_HCT_Hb_FE([FullBloodTest,PersData],hctLow),
        checkRBC([FullBloodTest,PersData],rbcLow),
        Diagnosis  = 'Iron Deficiency'.

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvLow),
        checkFerritin(FullBloodTest,ferLow),
        check_HCT_Hb_FE([FullBloodTest,PersData],hctLow),
        checkRBC([FullBloodTest,PersData],rbcHigh), 
        checkElectrHb([[Symptoms,ElectricalHb]],electro),   
        Diagnosis  = 'Minor Thalassemia'.


rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvLow),
        checkFerritin(FullBloodTest,ferLow),
        check_HCT_Hb_FE([FullBloodTest,PersData],hctHigh),
        checkRBC([FullBloodTest,PersData],rbcHigh), 
        checkElectrHb([[Symptoms,ElectricalHb]],electro),   
        Diagnosis  = 'Minor Thalassemia'.



rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptNeg), 
            Diagnosis  = 'There is not problem with anemia.'.

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvNormal),
        checkFerritin(FullBloodTest,ferHigh),
        checkElectrofHb([Symptoms,ElectricalHb],yesElectr),
        Diagnosis='Thalassemia'.

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),      
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvHigh),
        check_B12_RBC([PersData,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest],b12Low),
        Diagnosis = 'B12 Anemia'.

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia) ,
        check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),      
        check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvHigh),
        check_Folic(SpecBloodTest,folic),
        Diagnosis = 'Folic Acid Anemia'.        

rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  %OK 
        check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,yesPancytopenia),
        Diagnosis = 'Check bone marrow'.


symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos) :-
    check_symptomList(Symptoms), !.
symptoms(Symptoms,symptNeg).




check_symptomList([H|T]) :-
    SymptomList = ['Πονοκέφαλος', 'Αδυναμία', 'Έλλειψη αυτοσυγκέντρωσης',
        'Απώλεια βάρους', 'Απώλεια όρεξης', 'Ωχρότητα',
        'Επώδυνη σπλήνα', 'Ταχυκαρδία', 'Δύσπνοια','Γλωσσίτιδα','Πληγές', 
        'Ελλειπής διατροφή', 'πατερας_Στίγμα', 'πατερας_Μεσογειακή',
        'μητερα_Στίγμα', 'μητερα_Μεσογειακή', 'Ιδιαίτερο'],
    member(H,SymptomList).
check_symptomList([H|T]) :- 
     check_symptomList(T).



check_WBC_PLT([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT], noPancytopenia) :- 
     number(WBC), number(PLT),
        (WBC > 4500, PLT>150)
;       number(WBC), number(PLT),(WBC > 4500, PLT=<150)
;       number(WBC), number(PLT),(WBC =< 4500, PLT>150).

check_WBC_PLT([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],yesPancytopenia) :- 
    number(WBC), number(PLT),
        (WBC =< 4500, PLT=<150).



check_RTC([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],rtcLess2):-
        number(RTC),RTC=<2.
check_RTC([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],rtcUp2):-
        number(RTC),RTC>2.


check_MCV([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],mcvLow):-
        number(MCV), MCV=<79.

check_MCV([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],mcvNormal):-
        number(MCV), MCV>79,MCV<97.

check_MCV([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],mcvHigh):-      
        number(MCV), MCV=<97.


check_HBS([HbA1,HbA2,HbS,HbF,Schema_RBC],hbSZero):-
        number(HbS), HbS=0,
        Schema_RBC='Σφαίρα'.

check_HBS([HbA1,HbA2,HbS,HbF,Schema_RBC],hbSZero):-
        number(HbS), HbS=0.     

check_HBS([HbA1,HbA2,HbS,HbF,Schema_RBC],hbsUpZero):-   
        number(HbS), HbS>0,
        Schema_RBC=='Δρεπάνι'.  
check_HBS([HbA1,HbA2,HbS,HbF,Schema_RBC],hbsUpZero):-   
        number(HbS), HbS>0.     

checkFerritin([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],ferLow):-
        number(Ferritin),Ferritin=<20.
checkFerritin([WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],ferHigh):-
        number(Ferritin),Ferritin>20.       

checkElectrofHb([Symptoms, ElectricalHb],electro):-       
     Symptoms = ['Πονοκέφαλος', 'Αδυναμία', 'Έλλειψη αυτοσυγκέντρωσης',
        'Απώλεια βάρους', 'Απώλεια όρεξης', 'Ωχρότητα',
        'Επώδυνη σπλήνα', 'Ταχυκαρδία', 'Δύσπνοια','Γλωσσίτιδα','Πληγές', 
        'Ελλειπής διατροφή', 'πατερας_Στίγμα', 'πατερας_Μεσογειακή',
        'μητερα_Στίγμα', 'μητερα_Μεσογειακή', 'Ιδιαίτερο'],
        ElectricalHb = [HbA1,HbA2,HbS,HbF,Schema_RBC],
        member('Ιδιαίτερο', Symptoms),
        (member('πατερας_Στίγμα', Symptoms), 
            member('μητερα_Μεσογειακή', Symptoms))
    ;   (member('πατερας_Μεσογειακή', Symptoms),
             member('μητερα_Στίγμα', Symptoms))
    ;   (member('πατερας_Μεσογειακή', Symptoms),
            member('μητερα_Μεσογειακή', Symptoms)),
        number(HbF),HbF>2,HbF<9,
        number(HbA1), HbA1<5.



check_HCT_Hb_FE([[WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],[Hlikia,Filo,Egkimosini]],hctLow):-  
        (Filo='male',number(Hct),number(Hb),number(Fe),Hct<40,Hb<14,Fe<55
        ; Filo='female',number(Hct),number(Hb),number(Fe),Hct<36,Hb<10,Fe<45
        ; Filo='male',Egkimosini=yes,number(Hct),number(Hb),number(Fe),Hct<36,Hb<12,Fe<55).


check_HCT_Hb_FE([[WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],[Hlikia,Filo,Egkimosini]],hctHigh).

checkRBC([[WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],[Hlikia,Filo,Egkimosini]],rbcLow):-
        (Filo='male',number(RBC),RBC<4.5);
        (Filo='female',number(RBC),RBC<3.8).

checkRBC([[WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],[Hlikia,Filo,Egkimosini]],rbcHigh):-
        (Filo='male',number(RBC),RBC>6);
        (Filo='female',number(RBC),RBC>4.9).


checkElectrHb([Symptoms, ElectricalHb],electro):-     
     Symptoms = ['Πονοκέφαλος', 'Αδυναμία', 'Έλλειψη αυτοσυγκέντρωσης',
        'Απώλεια βάρους', 'Απώλεια όρεξης', 'Ωχρότητα',
        'Επώδυνη σπλήνα', 'Ταχυκαρδία', 'Δύσπνοια','Γλωσσίτιδα','Πληγές', 
        'Ελλειπής διατροφή', 'πατερας_Στίγμα', 'πατερας_Μεσογειακή',
        'μητερα_Στίγμα', 'μητερα_Μεσογειακή', 'Ιδιαίτερο'],
        ElectricalHb = [HbA1,HbA2,HbS,HbF,Schema_RBC],      
         member('πατερας_Στίγμα', Symptoms);
         member('μητερα_Στίγμα', Symptoms);
         member('μητερα_Μεσογειακή', Symptoms);
         member('πατερας_Μεσογειακή', Symptoms),
        number(HbF),HbF>2,HbF<9,
        number(HbA1), HbA1<1.

check_B12_RBC([[Hlikia,Filo,Egkimosini],[WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,FE,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],[B12,Folic_acid,tSH,Kreatinin]],b12Low):-
        (Filo='male',number(RBC),RBC>6);
        (Filo='female',number(RBC),RBC>4.9),
        number(B12), B12<130.

check_Folic([B12,Folic_acid,tSH,Kreatinin],folic):-
        number(Folic_acid), Folic_acid<3.1.
```

The kb code file is

```
:- dynamic kb_da/4.


kb_da(patient1,['Ιωάννης Ιωάννου','Φλέμινγκ3 71410 Ηράκλειο','2810123456'],
     [50,male,na],[['Πονοκέφαλος','Aδυναμία','Έλλειψη αυτοσυγκέντρωσης'],_,_,_]).

     %Sidiropenik Anaimia   
kb_da(patient2,
    ['Δημήτρης Παπαδημητρίου','Αρχαγγέλου 17 Κοκκινοτριμιθιά Λευκωσίας','0035797273515'],
       [27,male,na], [['Πονοκέφαλος','Κούραση','Ταχυκαρδία','Δύσπνοια'],
    [4800,1,75,4.3,45,18,280,33,12,125],_,_]).

kb_da(patient3,['Δέσποινα Μπασδέκη','Πανός 19 71410 Ηράκλειο',6955457845],[24,female,no],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Έλλειψη αυτοσυγκέντρωσης','Ελλειπής διατροφή','Δύσπνοια','Ταχυκαρδία'],
        [4300,1,75,3.7,41,18,250,30,10,180],_,_]).

kb_da(patient4,['Δήμητρα Περπερίδου','Καραμανώλη 5 55142 Θεσσαλονίκη',6977458521],[32,female,yes],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Έλλειψη αυτοσυγκέντρωσης','Ελλειπής διατροφή','Δύσπνοια','Ταχυκαρδία','Ταχυκαρδία'],
        [4800,1,72,3.7,50,15,280,32,10,180],_,_]).

 %Stigma Mesogeiaki Anaimia 

kb_da(patient5,['Manolis Manolaou','Epaminondos 24 55142 Θεσσαλονίκη',6985245125],[50,male,na],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Δύσπνοια','Ταχυκαρδία','Ταχυκαρδία','μητερα_Στίγμα'],
        [4800,1,78,7,45,15,320,39,13,125],_,_]).        

kb_da(patient6,['Manolis Pavlou','Venizelou 24 59100 Veroia',6977148545],[25,male,na],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Δύσπνοια','Ταχυκαρδία','πατερας_Μεσογειακή',],
        [4800,1,78,7.8,45,15,320,39,13,155],_,_]).


kb_da(patient7,['Maria Papadopoulou','Venizelou 24 59100 Veroia',6985478452],[42,female,na],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Δύσπνοια','Ταχυκαρδία','Ελλειπής διατροφή','μητερα_Μεσογειακή'],
        [4800,1,78,7.8,45,15,320,39,13,155],_,_]).


% Mesogeiaki Anaimia    

kb_da(patient8,['Μαρία Παπανικολάου','Βετσοπούλου 24 59100 Αλεξάνδρεια',6974582545],[42,female,no],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Δύσπνοια','Αδυναμία','Ταχυκαρδία','Ελλειπής διατροφή','πατερας_Στίγμα','μητερα_Μεσογειακή','Ιδιαίτερη'],
        [4800,1,85,5.5,45,22,320,39,13,155],_,
        [3,hbA2,hbS,5,schema_RBC]]).

kb_da(patient9,['Γεώργιος Παπαδήμου','Παπανικολάου 58 47854 Βόλος',6974585124],[85,male,na],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Ωχρότητα','πατερας_Μεσογειακή','πατερας_Μεσογειακή','Ιδιαίτερο'],
        [4800,1,85,5.5,45,22,320,39,13,155],_,
        [3,hbA2,hbS,5,schema_RBC]]).


kb_da(patient10,['Γεώργιος Καρανικόλας','Χαριλάου Τρικούπη 58 56954 Θεσσαλονίκη',6974585412],[45,male,na],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Ωχρότητα','πατερας_Μεσογειακή','μητερα_Στίγμα','Ιδιαίτερη'],
        [4400,1,75,5.5,45,22,320,39,13,125],_,
        [4,hbA2,hbS,2,schema_RBC]]).        

%Β12

kb_da(patient11,['Παναγιώτης Μπομπότης','Αιγαίου 3 17122 Ν.Σμύρνη Αττικης ',6974585123],[22,male,no],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Ωχρότητα','Απώλεια βάρους','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4400,1,100,3.5,45,22,320,39,13,125],
        [125,3.5,tSH,creatinine],_]).       



kb_da(patient12,['Δήμητρα Καρανικόλα','Χαριλάου Τρικούπη 58 56954 Θεσσαλονίκη',6974585412],[24,female,na],
        [['Απώλεια βάρους','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4800,1,100,3.7,45,22,320,39,13,170],
        [125,2,tSH,creatinine],_]).     

%Foliko O3i


kb_da(patient13,['Κίμωνας Ιωαννίδης','Βρυλήσια Αττικής',6984575625],[65,male,no],
        [['Απώλεια βάρους','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4800,1,100,5.5,45,22,320,39,13,170],
        [125,2,tSH,creatinine],_]). 


kb_da(patient14,['Ιουλια Αναστασιάδου','Κουντουριωτη 3 54625 Θεσσαλονίκη',6958475202],[35,female,yes],
        [['Απώλεια βάρους','Ωχρότητα','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4800,1,100,3.7,45,22,320,39,13,170],
        [145,2,tSH,creatinine],_]). 

%Drepanokitarwsi

kb_da(patient15,['Βασίλης Παπακωσταντίνου','Μητροπόλεως 18 74125 Ν. Ιωνία',6955447751],[35,male,no],
        [['Απώλεια βάρους','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4800,2,100,3.7,45,22,320,39,13,170],
        [hbA1,hbA2,1,hbF,'Δρεπάνι'],_]).    

kb_da(patient16,['Θοδωρής Onir','Καραμανλή 45 74125 Ν.Ιωνία',6977457845],[38,male,no],
        [['Απώλεια βάρους','Ωχρότητα','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4400,2,100,3.7,45,22,320,39,13,170],
        [hbA1,hbA2,2,hbF,'Δρεπάνι'],_]).            


%Σφαιροκυττάρωση

kb_da(patient17,['Όλγα Σαμανίδου','Κηφισιάς 45 74125 Κηφισιά',6985544125],[29,female,yes],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Δύσπνοια','Αδυναμία','Απώλεια βάρους','Ωχρότητα','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4900,2,100,3.2,45,28,320,39,13,120],
        [hbA1,hbA2,0,hbF,'Σφαίρα'],_]).


kb_da(patient18,['Σοφία Χατζηπαυλή','Γεωργίου Βλαστού 12 45785 Κώς',6974545455],[18,female,no],
        [['Πονοκέφαλος','Αδυναμία','Ωχρότητα','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4900,2,100,3.2,45,28,320,39,13,170],
        [hbA1,hbA2,0,hbF,'Σφαίρα'],_]). 

%Den iparxei provlima

kb_da(patient19,['Βλάση Μπονάτσο','Παπαμιχαήλ 54 14585 Αθήνα',6985545212],[58,male,no],
        [['Αδυναμία','Ωχρότητα','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4900,2,100,3.2,45,28,320,39,13,170],
        [hbA1,hbA2,0,hbF,'Κανονικό'],_]).

kb_da(patient20,['Μαρία Παπαμιχαήλ','Κονίτσης 54 59100 Βέροια',6984525154],[42,female,no],
        [['Αδυναμία','Ωχρότητα','Απώλεια όρεξης'],
        [4900,2,99,3.2,45,28,320,45,13,170],
        [hbA1,hbA2,2,hbF,'Κανονικό'],_]).
```

Comment: For one, there is an odd disjunction in check_WBC_PLT. I have adjusted indentation to better show you where that problem lies.

Comment: i run the code with changes but the same result again..
What do you mean an odd disjunction??

Comment: The indentation should make it clear: `number(WBC), number(PLT),` is part of the first disjunct only.

Comment: Ohh,..now i undrstAND...
Just a sec to correct this..

Comment: Same again..
"There is no problem with anemia"..

I think maybe the fault is in symptoms predicate..
Bacause the first time that fails and tries to run the other rule it take symptoms negative so it returns "There is no problem"

Comment: There is too much second-guessing going on. Say, your rule in the beginning has  this first goal `clause/2`. Why does that succeed at all? No indication whatsoever in your program.

Comment: The symptoms predicate checks that at least one is member of the list so it goes to the second predicate. Why not succeed?

Comment: The kb is in another file..that load from
:- ['kb_anemia_V4.pl'].

Assume that the kb is this
`kb_da(asthenis5,['Manolis Manolaou','Epaminondos 24 55142 Θεσσαλονίκη',6985245125],[50,male,na],
  [['Πονοκέφαλος','Δύσπνοια','Ταχυκαρδία','Ταχυκαρδία','μητερα_Στίγμα'],
  [4800,1,78,7,45,15,320,39,13,125],_,_]).  `

kb_da(Userid,DataCom,PersData,
 [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb])

Comment: We need a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), too much second guessing.

Comment: Do you want to edit the question and add the kb code and the full code of rules?

Comment: Which Prolog do you use? There is, `,]` which is syntactically invalid (search for it - in patient6).

Answer (score 3):

Here are some remarks.

1mo, always take the warnings a system generates seriously and remove them.  You have all kinds of singleton variables some of which are problems and some are not. And in fact, in rule `check_HCT_Hb_FE` there is `FE` and `Fe`.

```
check_HCT_Hb_FE([[WBC,RTC,MCV,RBC,Fe,Ferritin,TIBC,Hct,Hb,PLT],[Hlikia,Filo,Egkimosini]],hctLow):-
%                                 ^^ was FE
        (  Filo='male', * ...
        ;  Filo='female',number(Hct),number(Hb),number(Fe), Hct<36,Hb<10,Fe<45
        ;  Filo='male', * ...
        ).
```

2do, it is not clear to me that using `number/1` makes much sense. Arithmetic predicates like the `Fe<45` are testing for a valid value anyway and produce an error in case something is wrong.

3tio, there is some odd syntax (which is otherwise unrelated). Search for `person6` and `,]`.

4to, to localize the problem I added the following lines to your program:

```
:- op(950, fy, *).
*_.
```

In this case it was quite easy since you said that Iron deficiency is expected:

```
rule(kb_da(UserId,DataCom,PersData,
    [Symptoms,FullBloodTest,SpecBloodTest,ElectricalHb]), Diagnosis) :- 
        * symptoms(Symptoms,symptPos),  
        * check_WBC_PLT(FullBloodTest,noPancytopenia),
        * check_RTC(FullBloodTest,rtcLess2),
        * check_MCV(FullBloodTest,mcvLow),
        * checkFerritin(FullBloodTest,ferLow),
        check_HCT_Hb_FE([FullBloodTest,PersData],hctLow),
        * checkRBC([FullBloodTest,PersData],rbcLow),
        Diagnosis  = 'Iron Deficiency'.
```

The highly generalized program already failed, so it was evident that the problem was within that goal `check_HCT_Hb_FE/2` in particular the failing goal was

```
check_HCT_Hb_FE([[4300,1,75,3.7,41,18,250,30,10,180],[24,female,no]],hctLow)
```

However, the three conditions `Hct<36,Hb<10,Fe<45` are not true in this case, in fact they are instantiated to `30<36,10<10,41<45` and `10<10` does not hold.

Comment: How can i use this op to localize other problems/??

Comment: @DebbieMp: With pure monotonic code, you can use `*` in any program where you have an unexpected failure.

Comment: For further examples of this techniques - look at the "Linked" item given on the right side. There you have a collection of such examples.